# Contest Challenge: "Maximize number of races one can take part in"

Tags: algorithm

While practising problems from hackerearth I came across following problem( not from active contest ) and have been unsuccessful in solving it after many attempts.

> Chandler is participating in a race competition involving N track
>   races. He wants to run his old car on these tracks having F amount of
>   initial fuel. At the end of each race, Chandler spends si fuel and
>   gains some money using which he adds ei amount of fuel to his car.
>
> Also for participating in race i at any stage, Chandler should have
>   more than si amount of fuel. Also he can participate in race i once.
>   Help Chandler in maximizing the number of races he can take part in if
>   he has a choice to participate in the given races in any order.

How can I approach the problem. My approach was to sort by `(ei-si)` but than I couldn't incorporate condition that fuel present is greater than required for race.

**EDIT** I tried to solve using following algorithm but it fails,I also can't think of any inputs which fail the algorithm. Please help me out figuring whats wrong or give some input where my algorithm fails.

```
Sort (ei-si) in non-increasing order;
start iterating through sorted (ei-si) and find first element such that fuel>=si
   update fuel=fuel+(ei-si);
   update count;
   erase that element from list, and start searching again;

if fuel was not updated than we can't take part in any races so stop searching 
and output count.
```

**EDIT** And here is my code as requested.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<list>

using namespace std;
struct race{
    int ei;
    int si;
    int earn;


};

bool compareByEarn(const race &a, const race &b)
{
    return a.earn <= b.earn;
}

int main(){

    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        vector<struct race> fuel;
        int f,n;
        cin>>f>>n;
        int si,ei;
        while(n--){
            cin>>si>>ei;
            fuel.push_back({ei,si,ei-si});

        }
        sort(fuel.begin(),fuel.end(),compareByEarn);
        list<struct race> temp;
        std::copy( fuel.rbegin(), fuel.rend(), std::back_inserter(temp ) );


        int count=0;
        while(1){


            int flag=0;
            for (list<struct race>::iterator ci = temp.begin(); ci != temp.end(); ++ci){
                if(ci->si<=f){
                    f+=ci->earn;
                    ci=temp.erase(ci);
                    ++count;
                    flag=1;
                    break;

                }
            }

            if(!flag){
                break;
            }
        }

        cout<<count<<endl;

    }


}
```

**EDIT** As noted in answer below, the above greedy approach dosen't always work. So now any alternative method would be useful

Comment: Have a look at the 0-1 Knapsack problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) - it's not exactly the same, but should give you some ideas.

Comment: I can't think of how to incorporate fuel constraint into it. Can you help there?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that for each "completed" race, working in the order of `ei-si` is the right approach. Once that is done, you might find yourself able to compete in a few more races with really low `si` - just because you still have some fuel left. But in the final calculation, for each completed race up to that point it matters that you lose the least amount of fuel. Interesting challenge.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Updated with my code, please help

Comment: Your comparison function is wrong, it should return a.earn < b.earn.  Change that, see if it fixes it.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman I tried with that first, than i changed it to less than equal. None of them works.

Comment: Also, can si or ei be negative?

Comment: Ah, I was mistaken, the algorithm is not completely correct.  See Mohit Jain's answer, he is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution, which gets accepted by the judge:

1. Eliminate those races which have a profit (ei>si)
2. Sort by ei (in decreasing order)
3. Solve the problem using a dynamic programming algorithm.  (It is similar to a pseudo-polynomial solution for the 0-1 knapsack.)

It is clear that the order in which you eliminate profitable races does not matter. (As long as you process them until no more profitable races can be entered.)

For the rest, I will first prove that if a solution exists, you can perform the same set of races in decreasing order of ei, and the solution will still be feasible.  Imagine we have a solution in which k races were chosen and let's say these k races have starting and ending fuel values of s1,...,sk and e1,...,ek.  Let i be the first index where ei < ej (where j=i+1).  We will show that we can swap i and i+1 without violating any constraints.

It is clear that swapping i and i+1 will not disrupt any constraints before i or after i+1, so we only need to prove that we can still perform race i if we swap its order with race i+1 (j).  In the normal order, if the fuel level before we start on race i was f, after race i it will be f-si+ei, and this is at least sj.  In other words, we have: f-si+ei>=sj, which means f-sj+ei>=si.  However, we know that ei < ej so f-sj+ej >= f-sj+ei >= si, and therefore racing on the jth race before the ith race will still leave at least si fuel for race i.

From there, we implement a dynamic programming algorithm in which d[i][j] is the maximum number of races we can participate in if we can only use races i..n and we start with j units of fuel.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

const int maxn = 110;
const int maxf = 110*1000;

int d[maxn][maxf];

struct Race {
    int s, e;
    bool used;
    inline bool operator < (const Race &o) const {
        return e > o.e;
    }
} race[maxn];

int main() {
    int t;
    for (cin >> t; t--;) {
        memset(d, 0, sizeof d);

        int f, n;
        cin >> f >> n;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cin >> race[i].s >> race[i].e;
            race[i].used = false;
        }

        sort(race, race + n);

        int count = 0;

        bool found;
        do {
            found = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (!race[i].used && race[i].e >= race[i].s && race[i].s >= f) {
                race[i].used = true;
                count++;
                f += race[i].s - race[i].e;
                found = true;
            }
        } while (found);


        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < maxf; j++) {
                d[i][j] = d[i + 1][j];
                if (!race[i].used && j >= race[i].s) {
                    int f2 = j - race[i].s + race[i].e;
                    if (f2 < maxf)
                        d[i][j] = max(d[i][j], 1 + d[i + 1][f2]);
                }
            }
        }

        cout << d[0][f] + count << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't understand dp part of program. Can u please elaborate a bit

Comment: I particularly don't understand why non decreasing order of ei works when profit is negative

Comment: Once we've established the order, every race is either used or not used.  If we have f fuel and enter race i, we can calculate the fuel after the race as f2, and then look at what races we can use after race i. (this is 1+d[i+1][f2]).  Alternatively, we can skip this race, in which case we just use d[i+1]

Comment: If there is a solution with an increasing ei, we can swap the first adjacent decreasing pair and the result is a solution which still works.  Therefore, we can process them in decreasing ei order.

Comment: I got DP part now thanks. But still don't understand if solution exists, decreasing order of ei is feasible

Comment: Sorry the parser dropped the rest of my sentence from where I had the < symbol!  I formatted it correctly now, see if it makes sense!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54647/discussion-between-tejas-patel-and-captaincodeman).

Comment: (+1) Good analysis and efficient solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your compareByEarn function

```
bool compareByEarn(const race &a, const race &b)
{
    if(a.earn == b.earn) return a.si < b.si;
    return a.earn < b.earn;
}
```

Above comparison means, choose the track with more earning (or lesser loss). But if there are 2 tracks with same earning, prefer the track which requires more fuel.

Consider the example

```
Initially fuel in the car = 4
track 1 : s = 2, e = 1
track 2 : s = 3, e = 2
track 3 : s = 4, e = 3

Expected answer = 3
Received answer = 2 or 3 depending on whether sorting algorithm is stable or unstable and the order of input\.
```

As a side note:

> Also for participating in race i at any stage, Chandler should have
>   more than si amount of fuel
>   Should translate to

```
if(ci->si < f){ // and not if(ci->si<=f){
```

You can check if my observation is right or problem author chose incorrect sentence to describe the constraint.

**EDIT**
 With more reasoning I realized you can not do it with only greedy approach.

Consider the following input.

```
Initially fuel in the car = 9
track 1 : s = 9, e = 6
track 2 : s = 2, e = 0
track 3 : s = 2, e = 0
track 4 : s = 2, e = 0

Expected answer = 4
Received answer = 3
```

Comment: Nope your suggestion for changing comparison function dosen't work

Comment: With more reasoning I realized you can not do it with only greedy approach.

Comment: What approach should I use than? Where does my algorithm goes wrong with greedy approach?

Comment: Can you check my updated edit. You need to think how should you choose the order better.

Comment: Can you please tell if you have any idea for ordering or selecting tracks?

Comment: I thought you are looking for the failing case. About idea, (untested but) You can greedily choose the track running on which you are left with the maximum number of options in remaining tracks to run next. Complexity is O(n^2). Should be fine for your requirement if number of tracks is less than 10000.

Comment: Can you please explain your approach in answer. I am not getting you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54605/discussion-between-tejas-patel-and-mohit-jain).